# Does any shortcut exists for swapping table rows including attributes of input elements inside those rows

Tags: jquery

Does any shortcut exists for swapping table rows including attributes of input elements inside those rows.

**EDIT**: Actually I don't need to swap the attributes, but I need to swap values inside those.
My system has some connection between the attributes and save order.
attributes are like

```
a[0],b[0],c[0] etc.,
a[1],b[1],c[1] etc.,
```

so after swapping I need to get the values swapped.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get any shortcuts, But the below code gave the result that what I want.

```
jQuery("body").on("click",".up,.down",function(){
        var current_row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
        if ($(this).is(".up")) {
            if(current_row.prev().find("th").length==0){ //If this is title row
                row_need_to_replace    =   current_row.prev();
            }
        } else {
            row_need_to_replace    =   current_row.next();
        }
        if(row_need_to_replace.find("input,textarea").length>0)
        {
          var i=0;
          current_row.find(":input").each(function(){
            input_need_to_replace=row_need_to_replace.find(":input :eq("+i+")");
            temp   =   input_need_to_replace.val();
            input_need_to_replace.val($(this).val());
            $(this).val(temp);                
            i++;
          });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** There is no shortcut because I've never seen a UI where it makes sense to suddenly save data entered by the user in a different place.

Example: I have a table where you enter your first and last name. Since people have preferences which value to enter first, I can add a preference to my UI which allows them to swap the two rows. But the surname (UI) still goes into the surname (database) and the family name (UI) goes into the family name (database). Switching the rows doesn't suddenly link surname with family name.

Don't swap the attributes of the elements, just change the order of the table rows in the DOM:

```
row.insertBefore(row.prev());
```

That moves everything and keeps custom attributes intact.

Comment: Why do you need to swap the IDs? Won't the user be confused when his data is suddenly saved in a different place?

Comment: Actually I don't need to swap the attributes, but I need to swap values inside those. My system has some connection between the attributes and save order. attributes are like

a[0],b[0],c[0]
a[1],b[1],c[1]

so after swapping I need to get the values swapped.
please check my edit